# Rails resize images if the variant does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to create a helper method that will display a variant if the variant exists, otherwise it will enqueue a job to resize the photo. The problem I'm facing is that the job is enqueued and seems to be performed every time the page loads.  I would assume that after the job runs the first time it wouldn't need to run again because the variant would exist.

application_helper.rb:

```
  def render_img(img, params, opts = {})
    variant = img.variant(resize_to_fill: params, auto_orient: true, format: :jpg)
    if img.service.exist?(variant.key)
      image_tag variant, opts
    else
      ResizePhotoJob.perform_later(img.blob, resize_cmd: params)
      image_tag img, opts
    end
  end
```

resize_photo_job.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class ResizePhotoJob < ApplicationJob
   queue_as :default
   def perform(file, resize_cmd:nil)
     if resize_cmd.nil?
      file.variant(auto_orient: true, format: :jpg, quality: 90).processed
    else
      file.variant(resize_to_fit: resize_cmd, auto_orient: true, format: :jpg).processed
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do any of this. [`.processed`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html) looks like it can handle it for you:

> When you do want to actually produce the variant needed, call `processed`. This will check that the variant has already been processed and uploaded to the service, and, if so, just return that. Otherwise it will perform the transformations, upload the variant to the service, and return itself again.

Comment: Yeah, it's doing 90% of what I want but the one big problem is that if a variant dosen't exist it will perform the transformations on the fly... I guess going forward this isn't a huge issue since we are processing new images, but I worry that if we change variant sizes performance will tank when users hit the site and Rails tries to resize all those images on the spot.